# Optimal Programming Environment

Tags: java, coldfusion, development-environment

My company is discussing changes to our work environment. I'm looking for any data on **Open Cubicle concept** (Take down the cubicle walls) vs **Silent cubicle** (No noise within within the working pit) environment and the effects on productivity. I've done some research and lots of "guides" boast benefits from both completely opposite views. I'm more interested in actual researched data then the latest blogs recommendation.
If you have experience in both environments the non-subjective Pros/Cons of each would be greatly appreciated. If it's of any relevance, my company works with Coldfusion and Java.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better to move this question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be more suited for your question. The specific tech you work with isn't relevant here at all, at least not software. Now, loud servers could be an issue, right? :)

Comment: Haha, I was expecting some IDE related question here. I guess the Java and Coldfusion tags are misleading. Anyway, what kind of development process model do you follow? There is some theory on this within the Agile world...

Comment: Oh, and my solution for the noise - **headphones** and grooveshark..

Comment: Question already asked on programmers.stackoverflow.com : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/11312/3508

Comment: IIRC, there is some data in DeMarco and Lister's Peopleware. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peopleware:_Productive_Projects_and_Teams

Comment: Noted, sorry for posting in the wrong exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked in open plan (60 devs+testers in one office) and in smaller offices of 3 or 4 people.

Personally, I felt more productive in a smaller office. There can be more distraction in a larger office from extrovert people, and also, for me, surprisingly, I find the communication to be less effective and more people seem to use email electronic communication instead of face to face. I think this is because the people who are introverts don't want to start a conversation with somebody in the middle of a 60 person office, because 15 people around you could be disturbed and could listen in on a conversation you only want to have with the person you're talking to.

For extroverts big offices, for introverts small offices. I'm not sure what most programmers are... there are definitely mixed opinions in the larger office as to whether it's good or not. But, I wonder if the people who say it's good generally enjoy catching up with gossip that spreads across the office instead of getting focused on what they're supposed to be doing?

What is essential for both is a communal meeting place such as a kitchen with a coffee machine where everybody can catch up on what's going on.